# Copy Row if Date is Month Today & =

Tags: excel-formula

I want to copy the data from column A,D & E if the date in A is today's month & column E is less than 99.96

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXVwQ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Filter function, you can do like this:

```
=FILTER(A2:E20;(MONTH(A2:A20)=MONTH(TODAY()))*(E2:E20<99,96);"nothing")
```

[image]